# Which extension methode will be used?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I cannot explain for myself which extension method matches the current MS API documentation, look at the screenshots.

There's an `IEnumerable.ToDictionary` method used with 3 parameters `FUNC key, FUNC Value, FUNC comparer`, in this order:

[image]

But within the MS API Doc [`IEnumerable` extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#hinweise-f%C3%BCr-ausf%C3%BChrende)
there seems no matching definition for the method above (key, value, comparer).

[image]

Who can explain this?

Comment: What about this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___1__? The last parameter is not a func, but an instance of `IEqualityComparer`.

Comment: @vasily.sib in this case, the image is helpful - it shows intellisense saying which overload was chosen.

Comment: @canton7 I can't see if there an intellisense or not. Anyway, image of code can't be helpful - it is alway useless.

Comment: @vasily.sib well it let me write an answer to the question, whereas all you left was a comment and a downvote, so different people can find value in different places I guess.

Comment: @canton7, you could write your answer only because you see these images. As for me (and many others SO users), my corporate firewall drops all images from imugr.com. Could you write your answer if you did not see these pictures too? Also, any user with similar question will be unable to find this question, because the most important part of this question is on some screenshot (you can't find anything by means of screenshot, right?). So, with my downvote, I simply motivate the freamworker to improve his question. To sum: images of text are always useless, sometimes they are even harmful.

Comment: @vasily.sib "always useless" is an overstatement. In this case, it was useful to me. I think I would struggle to understand the question and answer it without the image. Until you can look at the image, I think it's unfair for you to pass such strong judgement on this question. You can certainly complain that *you* can't answer the question because of it, and that's fair, but I don't think you can speak on behalf of me and others here.

Answer (score 1):

The comparer isn't a "FUNC" - it's a `new NonUniqueComparer()`, which I'm guessing is a type which implements `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Intellisense tells you that it's chosen the `(Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)` overload (where `TSource` is `'a`, `TKey` is `object`, and `TElement` is `object`), which is the bottom one in your screenshot.

Comment: Ahh, okay, so the first parameter of an extension method (this) will not be passed and not "communicated" via intelli sense. So the API counts 4 parameter ("this" included) and the real use not I guess now.

Comment: In intellisense, you're calling `r.ToDictionary(...)`. Here, it's already clear that `r` is the first `this` parameter, and so there's no point in Intellisense calling it out. If you had called `Enumerable.ToDictionary(r, ...)`, then Intellisense would show `r` as the first parameter.